# flutter - hand write something in the flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, package, digital-handwritting

I want to create an application like goodnotes. So i want the user to write something with a pen or with his finger so that it is **handwritten**. He could also save his note and modify whenever he wants.
Do you think there is a package for that ?

I have looked for a lot of packages.
I found scribble, but feels like it is impossible to save and remodify the notes a moment later, we can only export it as images.
Maybe there is a way to convert images into handwritten notes ?

Any ideas will be very appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.